# How to pass different `rapidjson::GenericObject`s to function?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17, rapidjson, generic-function

I have a function where I would like to pass a `rapidjson::GenericObject` as a parameter, e.g.

```cpp
MyObject readObject(rapidjson::GenericObject<true/false, rapidjson::Value>& obj)
{
    // ...
}
```

However, depending on how I extract the object, `GenericObject` is either `const` or not.

For example, it is

- When extracting from an array

  ```
  rapidjson::GenericObject<true, rapidjson::Value> // true
  ```
- When extracting from a doc

  ```
  rapidjson::GenericObject<false, rapidjson::Value>  // false
  ```

How can I have a function that can take both types of objects (`true` **and** `false`) so that I can then extract the members from it for further processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I have a function that can take both types of objects (`true` and `false`) so that I can then extract the members from it for further processing?

You can rewrite the `readObject` as a [template function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template), which will deduce the class template arguments. There you can get the non-template boolean, which can be used in [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if), (since  [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)) so that only the true branch will be retained at compile time.

Something like as follows:

```
template<bool Flag, typename T>
auto readObject(rapidjson::GenericObject<Flag, T>& obj)
{
    // T value{..code..} ;  // if needed!

    if constexpr (Flag) {
        // code for extracting from an array....
    }
    else {
        // code for extracting from a doc....
    }
}
```

[See a live demo in godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6Yoa6bozv)

---

Alternative to `if constexpr`, the solution can be [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)d, if you do not have C++17 compiler support.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed reply and the links! Since the code is the same for both `Flag == true` and `Flag == false` and `T` is always `rapidjson::Value`, it works with `template<bool Flag>
auto readObject(rapidjson::GenericObject<Flag, rapidjson::Value>& obj)`. However, there is one thing that is left: While having everything in the header file works, I had the function declaration in the header file while the definition was in a cpp file. Now I can't get it to work. Looking [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl), it does seem a bit complicated.

Comment: Yeah, I linked the same site in my reply, that's where I got the solution to simply move the definition to the header file from. I was hoping to get this part to work: "*The other solution is to leave the definition of the template function in the .cpp file and simply add the line template void foo<int>(); to that file:*", but I don't get it right in this case.